# How to implement negative infinity to positive infinity limit in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, infinity

I need to find the limit of

symsum(expression,variable,-Inf,Inf)

It gives error. How I can solve.

Comment: What is the error, and what is the expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the summation range in two. For example, to sum `1/(k+1/2)^2` for `k` ranging from `-inf` to `inf`:

```
>> syms k
>> S = symsum(1/(k+1/2)^2,1,inf) + symsum(1/(-k+1/2)^2,0,inf)
S =
pi^2
```